# How to rename all files to lowercase (solved) and simultaneously spaces to underscores

Tags: regex, perl, file-rename, batch-rename

I am trying to convert all files to lowercase in a directory tree and subsequently move spaces to underscores or hyphens. The first part I was able to get by searching which uses below code.

`find . -depth -print0 | xargs -r0 perl-rename -n 's/(.*)\/([^\/]*)/$1\/\L$2/;'`

Now I am trying to extend it to move spaces to _ also in a single regex but with no success till now. I tried with various combinations of \K operator as I think it'd be possible with that. Could you please help me out. The last command I tried was,

`find . -depth -print0 | xargs -r0 perl-rename -n 's/(.*)\/([^\/]*)/$1\/\L$2/;s/(.*)\/\K(\S+)\s+\g1/_/g;'`

but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
find . -depth -print0 | 
   xargs -0 perl-rename -n 's~([^/]+)$~\L$1~;s~(?:.*/|\G)\K(\S+)\s+(?![^/]*/)~$1_~g'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dG5pA9/7)

Comment: well, it changes the direcory if the filename has no spaces. For example
`./ringtones 1 space test/R2D2.mp3 -> ./ringtones_1_space_test/r2d2.mp3`
It replaced the space in directory also but there are files left to process in the directory which will fail then.

Comment: What is `perl-rename`? I'm vaguely aware of it as a utility that accompanies Perl , but I cannot find it in any of my Perl installations nor mention of it on the internet

Comment: On my host is called just `rename`. I used `prel-rename` from OP's question assuming it is some alias of same.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I assume it's [this](http://search.cpan.org/~pederst/rename-1.9/bin/rename.PL)

Comment: on Arch Linux, it comes as perl-rename.

Answer (score 2):

As [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) has indicated, the problem is with changing the names of directories while you are processing the tree. It is similar to the issue with modifying a Perl hash while you are iterating over it

This is the sort of thing that the [`File::Find` module's](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find) `finddepth` function is for. It will report a directory name only immediately before the scan is about to back out of it, and *after* all the contents have been reported

As long as you are running Perl v5.14 or better, so that `tr///` will accept the non-destructive susbtitution modifier `/r`, you can write it in one line like this

```
perl -MFile::Find=finddepth -e"finddepth(sub{ rename $_, tr/A-Z /a-z_/r }, '/path/to/root/dir')"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -depth -print0 | 
xargs -r0 perl-rename -n  's!([^/]+$)!lc($1 =~s/ /_/gr)!e'
```